# Display via Tesla graphic card

Tags: cuda, nvidia

I want to display a processed video on monitor. For video processing in CUDA, I am thinking to get a Nvidia Tesla grade card, but it does not have any video out port. Is there a way to create the frame buffer on the Tesla GPU card, then transfer it to system memory and display via motherboard graphics?

PS: I don't want to compute anything on CPU, to have a near real time performance.

Comment: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/hpc-visualization-nvidia-tesla-gpus/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For video processing (and display), and given what I understand of your problem, Tesla is probably not your best choice.

1. Tesla cards are expensive, (partly) because of double precision support, which you don't need for video processing
2. Tesla cards don't have any video port, meaning you have to send back your frames to system (obviously possible). That means a performance penalty, and more code to write and maintain.

Did you have a look to Quadro product line? They have display ouput, and are usually meant for this kind of applications (but still expensive).

If you want to display, that probably means you work on a desktop application. So you graphics card won't work 24/7 in full compute load? In that case, why not a GeForce?

Comment: I am using deep learning for processing the frames, Nvidia recommends tesla products for the computation and does not have any benchmarks for quadro cards as they are mostly for rendering.  I am exploring ways to display via tesla, if not available or consumes more resources, I will move to quadro.

Comment: Well, deep learning is a totally different topic. For training, a tesla will definitely be your best pick, but for inference, I guess not. What you need is probably many FP16 units, so if you absolutely need to do both inference and training on the same card, I would look to quadro gp100

Comment: Newer tesla cards are optimized for inference ( Tesla P4 and Tesla P40) which also support tensorRT Inference engine. Also GP100 is way too costly.